# how to use a label to display a math problem in swift

Tags: swift, math, label, character, line

I want to put a division problem in a swift label. The label would something like this
[image]
You can see the f(x) = . I dont know how I would write something like this in a single line. I know you can use the \n to form a new line but I dont think that would have any effect on this.

Comment: This isn't something that you're likely to accomplish with just first-party built-in tools. Perhaps doing some exploring of the libraries that are out there like https://github.com/kostub/iosMath